# How to vibrate Android device on button click using vibrator effects using Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, vibration

How to vibrate an Android device coding with Kotlin when pressing any buttons? I have used this code below, but there aren't any effects or vibrations performed.

```
//click listener
    imgNextBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val vibe:Vibrator = activity?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
        vibe.vibrate(500)
        Utilities.alertDialog(this,
                activity!!,
                mContent!!
    }
}
```

Or

```
 //click listener
    imgNextBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val vibe:Vibrator = activity?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
        var effect:VibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(1000, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE);

    vibe.vibrate(effect)
        
        Utilities.alertDialog(this,
                activity!!,
                mContent!!
    }
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.china.openkey">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: Have you added  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/> Permission in your manifest?

Comment: yes.. i have already added that permission in menifest

Comment: Where is it in your manifest? A [mcve] is most helpful.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can create a `fun` and use from it (`Kotlin`):

```
fun Fragment.vibratePhone() {
    val vibrator = context?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
    } else {
        vibrator.vibrate(200)
    }
}
```

And in your `fragment`:

```
vibratePhone()
```

Finally in you `manifest`:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: Will this work with Java too? It seems like it would?

Comment: @jojo Great work. Thanks 

Comment: shall combine with below answer for supporting SDK 31

Answer (score 13):

Answer given by @R2R is perfect. But `vibrate()` method of `Vibrator` class is **deprecated** from **API Level 26**. So, I am giving you the updated code:

You don't have to change everything. Just update the code for **vibration** in **MainActivity.kt**.

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        val btn_click_me = findViewById(R.id.btn_vibrate) as Button
        btn_click_me.setOnClickListener {
            val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
            if (vibrator.hasVibrator()) { // Vibrator availability checking
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)) // New vibrate method for API Level 26 or higher
                } else {
                    vibrator.vibrate(500) // Vibrate method for below API Level 26
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You create vibratorService with getSystemService, then your code doesn't use it. Instead, it uses something called vibrator, which you never created. I'm sure that's just a typo in your answer.

Comment: VIBRATOR service is deprecated

Answer (score 6):

Vibrator Service is deprecated for API 31 and above.
To do this the right way, do the following instead as addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466095/vibrator-service-string-is-deprecated-for-api-31):

```
 fun vibrate(){
    val vib = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        val vibratorManager =
            getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
        vibratorManager.defaultVibrator
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        vib.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(300, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE) )
    }else{
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        vib.vibrate(300)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Vibration using kotlin working sample try this

Manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

In kotlin:

```
 val vibratorService = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
        vibratorService.vibrate(500)
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_vibrate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vibrate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        val btn_click_me = findViewById(R.id.btn_vibrate) as Button
        btn_click_me.setOnClickListener {
            val vibratorService = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
            vibratorService.vibrate(500)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplify it could be like

```
val buzzer = activity?.getSystemService<Vibrator>()

buzzer?.let {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                buzzer.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(pattern, -1))
            } else {
                //deprecated in API 26
                buzzer.vibrate(pattern, -1)
            }
        }
```

When pattern could be like

```
val pattern = longArrayOf(0, 200, 100, 300)
```

Elements of buzzing and non-buzzing takes -> wait 0 ms, buzz 200ms, wait 100ms, buzz 300ms

Of course with permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Hope, it will help somebody in future

Answer (score 1):

To make your **phone vibrate** when a button is pushed, you can use the Vibrator class in Android. Here's how you can create a function to vibrate the device:

In `Kotlin`:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    fun Context.vibrator(durationMillis: Long = 50) {
        when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
                // For Android 12 (S) and above
                val vibratorManager = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
                val vibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(durationMillis, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)
                val vibrator = vibratorManager.defaultVibrator
                vibrator.vibrate(vibrationEffect)
            }

            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
                // For Android 8.0 (Oreo) to Android 11 (R)
                val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
                val vibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(durationMillis, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)
                vibrator.vibrate(vibrationEffect)
            }

            else -> {
                // For Android versions below Oreo (API level 26)
                val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
                vibrator.vibrate(durationMillis)
            }
        }
    }
```

In the `vibrator()` function, the code is divided into three sections: one for **Android 12 (S)** and above, another for **Android 8.0 (Oreo) to Android 11 (R)**, and the last one for versions below **Oreo (API level 26)**.

Make sure to adjust the behavior and vibration duration according to your needs in each section.

---

Also, don't forget to add the necessary permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to use the vibrator:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

---

To use this function, you can call it when the button is clicked.

in the **Activity** classes

```
myButton.setOnClickListener {
    vibrator(1000) // Vibrate for 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
}
```

or

```
myButton.setOnClickListener {
    vibrator() // Vibrate for 50 milliseconds
}
```

in the **non Activity** classes

```
myButton.setOnClickListener {
    context.vibrator(1000) // Vibrate for 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
}
```

or

```
myButton.setOnClickListener {
    context.vibrator() // Vibrate for 50 milliseconds
}
```