# How to programmatically enable/disable haptic feedback in System Settings in a device running SDK API level 30+?

Tags: android, android-settings, android-vibration, haptic-feedback

Since as of API level 30, *System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED* has been marked as deprecated,
how would one programmatically enable/disable haptic feedback in System Settings(i.e. globally) on a device running SDK API level 30+ using the *VibrationAttributes*-related APIs?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you found a solution by any chance ?

Comment: No. I ended up just disabling that feature in the app when OS version above 30 is detected. However, you may find some useful info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880450/how-to-vibrate-android-device-on-button-click-using-vibrator-effects-using-kotli